# android Admin is invalid or not white-listed

Tags: android, mobile

My android code is as below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,mDeviceAdmin);
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_ENABLE);
```

However, it did not open the admin UI as expected, it threw an Exception and cause my android app to crash.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Admin is invalid or not white-listed.

04-01 18:13:54.931 E/DeviceAdminAdd( 2748):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1467)

04-01 18:13:54.931 E/DeviceAdminAdd( 2748):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1421)

04-01 18:13:54.931 E/DeviceAdminAdd( 2748):     at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.setSilentActivation(IDevicePolicyManager.java:2631)

04-01 18:13:54.931 E/DeviceAdminAdd( 2748):     at android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.setSilentActivation(DevicePolicyManager.java:259)

04-01 18:13:54.931 E/DeviceAdminAdd( 2748):     at com.android.settings.DeviceAdminAdd.onCreate(DeviceAdminAdd.java:191)

04-01 18:13:54.931 E/DeviceAdminAdd( 2748):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1678)

04-01 18:13:54.931 E/DeviceAdminAdd( 2748):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:859)

04-01 18:13:54.931 E/DeviceAdminAdd( 2748):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)

04-01 18:13:54.931 E/DeviceAdminAdd( 2748):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
```

Answer (score 0):

In manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver"
        android:label="device_admin"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin"
               android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

add device_admin xml to the receiver it will work